# Image Border in Foreground

Tags: html, image, css

I am trying to put an image border around an image. I want the frame in foreground and the picture in the background.

The frame is a transparent PNG. In the example I want the cat to go behind the frame. How can I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
.frame{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 63px 84px 93px 98px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 stretch;
-o-border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 stretch;
border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 fill stretch;
}

<img class="frame" src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/100/f/2/cat_png_by_dbszabo1-d3dn2c8.png"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnb1/hc8z3phr/

Any help appreciated

Comment: If it's a picture _frame_, why does it matter that the picture must be in front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the image in a `<div>`, applying the frame to that div, and then, using relative positioning and z-indexing, drop the child `<img>` behind the parent `<div>`.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/100/f/2/cat_png_by_dbszabo1-d3dn2c8.png"/>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.frame {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 63px 84px 93px 98px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 stretch;
    border-image: url(http://dc346.4shared.com/img/kDajfqf9/s7/128d011efa0/black_frame) 63 84 93 98 fill stretch;
}
.frame img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hc8z3phr/11/)